# I keep having Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_error(): Argument #1 ($mysql) must be of type mysqli, bool given

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I would be really grateful if someone can help me solve my problems.
one of the problems is that when I enter correct data and press submit it keeps showing me this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_error(): Argument #1 ($mysql) must be of type mysqli, bool given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Try_Project/ServerForm.php:70 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/Try_Project/ServerForm.php(70): mysqli_error(false) #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/Try_Project/SignUp.php(16): include('/opt/lampp/htdo...') #2 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Try_Project/ServerForm.php on line 70
```

The other is that I can't display all errors which are Duplicate emails, duplicate phone number and the two passwords not matching.

this is the main signUp code:

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);  
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
<?php
 $duplicateEmail="";
 $duplicatePhone="";
 $notEqual="";
 $insertSuccess=false;
 $emailExist=false;
 $phoneExist=false;
 $passwordER=false;
 ?>

<?php include('ServerForm.php') ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>The Silk Flower</title>
    <meta charset="utf8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles1.css">
</head>
<body>
    <?php include('includes/header.php') ?>

     
    <br>
    <br>
    <center><div>
        
        <?php 
    if($insertSuccess){
    header('location: index.html');
    }
        ?>
         <!-- start of the sign up page --> 
        <h1 class="title">Sign up</h1>
    </div>

        <!-- sign up form --> 
    <form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" name="login" >

  <div class="container">
    <label for="Fname"><b>First Name</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="Fname" autofocus required>
    
    <label for="Lname"><b>Last Name</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="Lname" required>
    
    <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

    <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" minlength="8"  required>
    
    <label for="psww"><b>Confirm Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Re-enter Password" name="psww" minlength="8"  required>
    
    <label for="t"><b>Phone</b></label>
    <input type ="tel" placeholder="eg. 0500000000" name = "t" required pattern="[0]{1}[5]{1}[0-9]{8}" maxlength="10">
    
    <label for="add"><b>Address</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Address" name="add" maxlength="60" required>
    
        <div class="product">
            <button style="width: auto" type="submit" name = "submit">Sign up</button>
      </div>
      <?php
        if($emailExist){
        print("<br><p style='color:red; margin-left:10px;'>". $duplicateEmail." </p>");}
         if ($phoneExist){
               print("<br><p style='color:red; margin-left:10px;'>". $duplicatePhone." </p>");}
         if ($passwordER){
               print("<br><p style='color:red; margin-left:10px;'>". $notEqual." </p>");}
        ?> 

  </div>
</form>
</center>
 <p> 
    
          <strong> <a href = "#top"> <img src="images/arrowtop.png" width="40" height="40">
              </a></strong>
         </p>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is code for inserting into the database:

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);  
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
 <?php
// connect to the database
include('includes/db.php');   

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    
    
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $Fname=$_POST['Fname'];  
    $Lname=$_POST['Fname'];  
    $email=trim($_POST['email']); 
    $psw=trim($_POST['psw']);
    $psww=trim($_POST['psww']);
    $t=trim($_POST['t']);
    $add=trim($_POST['add']);

    $duplicateEmail=false;
    $emailExist=false;
    $duplicateEmail="";
    
    $duplicatePhone=false;
    $phoneExist=false;
    $duplicatePhone="";
    
    $notEqual=false;
    $passwordEr=false;
    $notEqual="";
   
    $checkexistemail="SELECT Email FROM Users WHERE Email='" .$_POST["email"]."'";
    $checkexistphone="SELECT Pnumber FROM Users WHERE Pnumber='" .$_POST["t"]."'";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($db,$checkexistemail);
    $result3 = mysqli_query($db,$checkexistphone);
 
    if (!($result2) || !($result3))
         {
         print ("<p> Query couldn't be executed </p>");
         echo mysqli_error($result2);
         echo mysqli_error($result3);
         }
     if (mysqli_num_rows($result2)>0){
         $emailExist=true;
         $duplicateEmail="This email address already exists, please enter a new one.";
         }
     if (mysqli_num_rows($result3)>0){
        $phoneExist=true;
        $duplicatePhone="This Phone number already exists, please enter a new one.";
    }
    if($psw != $psww){
        $passwordEr=true;
        $notEqual="The two passwords do not match.";
    }
    else{
        $insertSuccess=false;
          //insert user data into database
    $query="INSERT INTO 'Users'('Fname', 'Lname', 'Email', 'Password', 'Pnumber', 'Address') 
              VALUES('$Fname', '$Lname', '$email','$psw', '$t', '$add)";

        
        $insertResult = mysqli_query($db,$query);
        if($insertResult){
            $insertSuccess=true;
        }
        else{
            echo mysqli_error($insertResult);
        }     
         }
    }
          
}
else{
        echo mysqli_error($db);   
        $duplicateEmail="";
        $duplicatePhone="";
}
    mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You supply a result to [mysqli_error()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php), whereas you should have supplied a database handle. So replace:

```
$result2 = mysqli_query($db,$checkexistemail);
$result3 = mysqli_query($db,$checkexistphone);

if (!($result2) || !($result3))
     {
     print ("<p> Query couldn't be executed </p>");
     echo mysqli_error($result2);
     echo mysqli_error($result3);
     }
```

by:

```
$result2 = mysqli_query($db,$checkexistemail);
if (!$result2) {
    echo "<p> Query [$checkexistemail] couldn't be executed </p>";
    echo mysqli_error($db);
}
$result3 = mysqli_query($db,$checkexistphone);
if (!$result3) {
    echo "<p> Query [$checkexistphone] couldn't be executed </p>";
    echo mysqli_error($db);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, do have a solution for the inserting issue not working?

Answer (score 1):

my error was very simple I forgot to add a single quotation mark at the end near $add... very embarrassing.

I also fixed every mysqli_error